# PHP value from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, rest

I have a problem with JSON Array. How i can get value from 'orders' -> 'status'
This is body JSON body

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderId": "F3MXBWMG61151028GUEST000P01",
      "orderCreateDate": "2015-10-28T09:24:45.318+01:00",
      "notifyUrl": "http://server/payuint2/main/notify2",
      "customerIp": "127.0.0.1",
      "merchantPosId": "200003",
      "description": "TEST",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "totalAmount": "15000",
      "status": "NEW",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "TEST",
          "unitPrice": "15000",
          "quantity": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": {
    "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
    "statusDesc": "Request processing successful"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the code for now

```
$order_info_payu = json_decode($response,true);
 $order_status = $order_info_payu->orders->status;
```

or

```
 $order_status = $order_info_payu['orders']['status'];
```

when I only use

```
$order_status = $order_info_payu['orders']
```

then I have the content, but how to capture 'status' from 'orders'?

Comment: json_decode with second parameter set to true, converts objects to associative arrays - so `->` won’t work any more at all. And `orders` is itself an _array_ of objects - so you need to use a numeric index first, to access one of those objects. So `$order_info_payu['orders'][0]['status']`

Comment: Do `print_r($order_info_payu);` to see the structure, you will see the `0` there.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Now its working.

```
$order_status = $order_info_payu->orders[0]->status;
echo $order_status;
```

Inside **orders** object you have an **array** thats why you need to add **..->orders[0]->..**

see there is an

```
  {
  "orders": [ .... /* square brackets = an array inside the order object,*/ 
]
}
```

this  **square brackets** means that after **order object** there is an array and then inside that array there are other objects.